# Method to check if phone screen is on or not

Tags: java, android, xposed-framework

I'm trying to have an Xposed module check (on hardware button press) whether the phone screen is on or not. How would I do this, is there any method to check this? 
Thanks.
EDIT: This needs to work on API 17 or more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if the screen is on in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474367/how-can-i-tell-if-the-screen-is-on-in-android)

Comment: No sorry, forgot to add, I need this to work on API 17+, and IsScreenOn() doesn't apply for at least API 17.

Comment: `IsScreenOn()` Will definitely work on API 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any API under 20, you can use [IsScreenOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn()).

For API 20+, you can use [IsInteractive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isInteractive()) as `IsScreenOn` was deprecated in API 20.