# Detect if display is on (not just interactive) below API 20 from inside Service

Tags: android, android-screen

How to detect if display is on?

Requirements

- Must work on devices with API level >=17 and <20 (Android 4.2.2, 4.3, 4.4)
- **I am not asking for interactive state** like [Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) / [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isInteractive%28%29)#isScreenOn() / #isInteractive()
- Must work from inside a Service

Comment: DisplayManager and PowerManager are the only methods I know for this :/

Comment: DisplayManager should do the trick, it´s added in API 17...

Comment: That's what I initially also thought. However the method DisplayManager#getState() requires API 20

Answer (score 0):

With DisplayManager for example

```
DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
for (Display display : dm.getDisplays()) {
    if (display.getState() != Display.STATE_OFF) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: display.getState() requires API 20

Comment: You are right, maybe use the DisplayManagerCompat from the supportv4 library ? It should behave the same way

Comment: Unfortunately [DisplayManagerCompat#getDisplays()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/hardware/display/DisplayManagerCompat.html#getDisplays%28%29) returns [android.view.Display](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html) and not some _DisplayCompat_ I'd need Display#getState() which requires API 20

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple Broadcast receiver for screen sates (ON or OFF).Why don't you wanna use Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON ?.

Ref:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474367/how-can-i-tell-if-the-screen-is-on-in-android)

Comment: The Broadcast Receiver receives Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON. But please prove me wrong by providing code.

Comment: in that link you can see the code of broadcast receiver for screen_on and screen_off

Comment: And that receiver receives Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON

Comment: yea it receives.You dont want receiver to receive this (screen_on) event ??

Comment: No, because [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) of this event says _"For historical reasons, the name of this broadcast action refers to the power state of the screen but it is actually sent in response to changes in the overall interactive state of the device.

This broadcast is sent when the device becomes interactive which may have nothing to do with the screen turning on. To determine the actual state of the screen, use getState(). "_ (getState() requires API 20)

Comment: use can use DisplayManager for version greater then kitkat and PowerManager for version below

Comment: I know, but [PowerManager#isScreenOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn%28%29) and PowerManager#isInteractive()  provide me the interactive state. I want the display state.

Comment: SensorEventListener is also an option you can get brightness value in that listener and on the base of that we you can detect screen visiblity

Comment: Please post me code of your idea of SensorEventListener I am not aware off how to detect screen ON/OFF state through this.